# PowerShell Script to replace values in list not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell

I have a script that is supposed to go into a list and find a replace values with a different value in a column.  The error I get is '**You cannot call a method on null-valued expression**' pointing to this line ($oldurl.URL = $oldurl.URL.Replace("T9", "DR"))

Any idea what's wrong?

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$siteUrl = "https://[siteName]"

$webName = “Resources”

$listName = "Training"

$spSite = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteurl)

$spWeb = $spSite.OpenWeb($webName)

$spList = $spWeb.Lists[$listName]

Write-Host("URL: [$spList]")

foreach($Item in $spList.Items )

{

$oldurl = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUrlValue($Item["INUM"])

$oldurl.URL = $oldurl.URL.Replace("T9", "DR")

Write-Host("URL: [$oldurl]")

$Item.Update()

}

$spWeb.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `$Item["INUM"]` doesn't have a value at the first retrived item, so the `$oldurl` is NULL! and you can't use the `replace` function with a `NULL` string

So you should check if the `$oldurl` is not null before calling the replace function as the following:

```
foreach($Item in $spList.Items)
{
$oldurl = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUrlValue($Item["INUM"])
if ($oldur -eq $null)
{continue}
else
{
  $oldurl.URL = $oldurl.URL.Replace("T9", "DR")
  Write-Host("URL: [$oldurl]")
  $Item.Update()
}

}
```

or

```
foreach($Item in $spList.Items)
{
$oldurl = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUrlValue($Item["INUM"])
if ($oldur -ne $null)

{
  $oldurl.URL = $oldurl.URL.Replace("T9", "DR")
  Write-Host("URL: [$oldurl]")
  $Item.Update()
}
 else continue

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Mohamed said, you could add a judgment statement to avoid the null value exception，
and you need to re-assign the modified value to item.

```
foreach($Item in $spList.Items)
{
$oldurl = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUrlValue($Item["INUM"])
if ($oldur -ne $null)

{
  $oldurl.URL = $oldurl.URL.Replace("T9", "DR")
  Write-Host("URL: [$oldurl]")
$Item["INUM"]= [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUrlValue]$oldurl
  $Item.Update()
}
 else continue

}
```